# Algorithm for the each item

Tags: java, algorithm

Product A costs $10 , B costs $3 and C costs $0.50.
A person bought 100 items for $100. How many of each item did the person buy.

I found the answer as-

```
94 * 0.5 = 47 
1 * 3    =  3    
5 * 10  =  50
```

But I am not able to implement it in java as the solution I got the result from Hit and Trial.
What will be the algorithm for solving this problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Plain brute-force:

```
   for (int i1 = 0; i1 <= 10; i1++) {
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 34; i2++) {
            int i3 = 100 - i2 - i1;
            int total = i1 * 10 + i2 * 3 + i3 / 2;
            if (total == 100 && i3 % 2 == 0)
                System.out.println(i1 + " * 10 + " + i2
                        + " * 3 + " + i3 + " * 0.5 = 100");

        }
    }
```

Gives two answers:

- 0 * 10 + 20 * 3 + 80 * 0.5 = 100
- 5 * 10 + 1 * 3 + 94 * 0.5 = 100

P.S. of course, it's not the optimal solution, but for just three items and 100 total amount - it's fine (and optimal from the point of time required to code it).

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement your algorithm for solving these two equations

```
A   +  B + C    = 100 -----------(1)
10A + 3B + 0.5C = 100 -----------(2)
```

From(2), we can figure out that:

```
C = 100 - A - B
```

Substitue this information in (2)

```
10A + 3B + 0.5 * ( 100 - A - B) = 100
This reduces to 
19A + 5B = 100
```

Then you can deduct that:

```
B = 20 - (19A/5)
```

Now,try to find out (using an int loop) for what "whole" value of `A`, will `B` become a whole value ( as normally in such problems, you always buy whole commodities -like fruits no fractions)

You will find that when A=5, B=1.

Keep solving the equation this way, and replace A, B and C with Java variables and you will be able to proivide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions can be found very easily. ring bearer already gave almost the entire way of doing this. ring bearer ended with:

```
B = 20 - (19A/5)
```

We know something else, though:

```
A, B, and C are all non-negative integer values.
```

This means 19A/5 has to be (1) an integer (else B would not be an integer), and (2) at most 20 (else B would be negative). This means for (1), that A has to be a multiple of 5, and for (2), that A has to be at most 5.

Also note that the requirement 19A/5 <= 20 can be rewritten as:

```
19A <= 100
```

There are only two values for A that satisfy this: 0 and 5. A very fast way to find all solutions then would be to do something like:

```
for (A = 0; 19*A <= 100; A += 5)
{
  // Show the solution for this value of A (with B = 20 - 19A/5 and C = 100 - A - B).
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant of the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) and you can look for a [dynamic-programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) based solution, which cab be better than brute force (in terms of computational complexity). A simple search yielded links like [this](http://jhave.org/learner/misc/knapsack/knapsack.shtml)